Huawei N2000 12 Disk Server Not Powering On Enough to Boot
I have a Huawei N2000 storgage server running Windows Storage Server 2016 with dual power supplies.  I powered it down due to an upcoming scheduled power cut and can not get it to powerup properly now the power is back on.  The device was plugged into an APC UPS.
When plugging the device back into the power, it initially starts to turn on and you can hear the fans kick in.  The orange lights on the NIC ports light up along with the lights indicating action on each of the disks.  It will stay like this for about five seconds before the fans go back to idle and the disk lights go out.  It will go through this cycle about 10 to 15 times before the fans stay at idle continually.  At no point is there any output to the monitor.
I have tried the following to get it to boot.

Swapped both power supplies out for spares I had.
Removed the BIOS battery.
Removed all RAM. Also tried with just one stick.
Removed all storage disks.
Removed all boot disks.

I am unable to get into the BMC as it appears it isn't configured.
Does anyone have any suggestions on what to try next please?
Many thanks

The attrition rate of hardware increases with age.
